# How to update DictA with data in DictB without changing the DictA struture in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In my use case, I want to update random data provided with DictB in the Already existing DictA without Changing the hierarchical structure.

```
dictA = {'Service': {'Name': 'MyService', 'Tag': {'MyTag'}, 'Host': 'myHost'}, 'Route':{}}
dictB =  {'Service': {'Name': 'MyService', 'Tag':{'MyTag1','MyTag2','MyTag3'}}}
```

My code:

```
dictA.update(dictB)
```

Output should be:

```
dictA = {'Service': {'Name': 'MyService', 'Tag': {'MyTag1', 'MyTag2', 'MyTag3'}, 'Host': 'myHost'}, 'Route':{}}
```

But it's giving me errors saying the structure is not valid.

Comment: Because two dictionaries are not of same structures.

Comment: Actually I am creating this dict from a YAML file which is containing config for my API, every time New container is created the YAML should be updated with a new host and tag, maybe sometimes routes also but it's random, which means the data is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dictA = {'Service': {'Name': 'MyService', 'Tag': {'MyTag'}, 'Host': 'myHost'}, 'Route':{}}
    dictB =  {'Service': {'Name': 'MyService', 'Tag':{'MyTag1','MyTag2','MyTag3'}}}
    c={}
    for x,y in dictA.items():
        c[x]=y
    for k,v in dictB.items():
        c[k]=v
    print(c)
```

> you cant change the dictionary A to take union of A & B but you can
> create a new dictionary which contains union of dictionary a and b
> without changing the hierarchical of A structure.

Comment: please reply if you get your answer

Comment: I did a little trick in this and got the solution after days long digging.

I broke the dict A in two parts using the 1st child, here service and route.

Comment: my solution worked for you or not

Answer (score 0):

```
    new_dict1 = dictA['Service']
    new_dict2 = dictB['Service']
    for k,v in new_dict1.items():
        for i,j in new_dict2.items():
            if k == i:
                if v != j:
                    if type(v) is list:
                        v = v + j
                        new_dict1[k] = list(set(v))
                    else:
                        new_dict1[k] = j
    print(new_dict1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).